# Linq "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'" error

Tags: c#, linq, oracle

I am using linq to extract some information from database.

**Sql script:**

```
    TYPE CURS IS REF CURSOR;

    CREATE OR REPLACE
    PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME (
        Cursor1 OUT CURS)
    AS
    BEGIN
        OPEN Cursor1 FOR
            SELECT NO, TITLE, TO_CHAR(STARTDATE) STARTDATE
            FROM TABLE_1;
    END;
```

**Linq code:**

```
    var query = from e in getItem().AsEnumerable()
                select new {
                    No = e.Field<string>("NO"),
                    Title = e.Field<string>("TITLE"),
                    StartDate = e.Field<string>("STARTDATE")
                };

    return query.Select(e => new ClassA()
    {
        No = e.No,
        Title = e.Title,
        StartDate = e.StartDate
    }).ToList<ClassA>();
```

**Class A:**

```
    public class ClassA {
        public string No { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**getItem():**

```
    public DataTable getItem() {
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Cursor1", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

But the query always return me error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.` but i already check that the STARTDATE is extracted as System.String. How to solve this? Its killing me..

---

**[UPDATE]**

It works now, I change all the data type of STARTDATE to `DateTime` and extract it from database without conversion.

But still, I do not understand why the error will appear.

Comment: What happens if you do `StartDate = e.Field<DateTime>("STARTDATE")`?  Does that work?

Comment: The same error still prompt out

Comment: Are you using the result of your SQL query in the LINQ statement, or are you trying to build a LINQ statement that will do the same thing as your SQL query?

Comment: What does your `TO_CHAR` function return?  It's likely returning a date type rather than a VARCHAR.

Comment: `TO_CHAR` is an Oracle method that returns a `VARCHAR2`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Comment: Yes I am using the result from my SQL query

Comment: TO_CHAR is an Oracle function to convert various datetimes or intervals to a VARCHAR2.

Comment: Maybe something within `GetItem()` is converting it back to a DATETIME?  Not sure why that would be, but I don't see any other issues with your posted code.

Comment: I also don't know why. I have already debug the process very thoroughly and the StartDate is returned as System.String.

Comment: Yes, we need to see the code for `GetItem()` also what line does that error report?

Comment: Added code for getItem() as requested.

Comment: try to use different name other than `STARTDATE` in your class for debugging purpose.

Comment: You have `Cursor` but there is no `Cursor` in given SQL, can you update question with full Stored procedure code?

Comment: change the field name in your sql to be STARTDATE2 and change it accordingly in your code and see what happens..

Comment: Extracting without conversion is the better approach anyway because you are accepting whatever NLS_LANGUAGE settings are there on the server.  This might not correspond to what is on the client.  Having said that I cannot see anything in your code which would explain the error message.  Did you try changing the field name as Eren suggested ?

Comment: @noobie please include your 'Update' to the answers so that your question will have a formal answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure, remove the function TO_CHAR. This function will convert datetime columns to varchar2 columns.

```
TYPE CURS IS REF CURSOR;

CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME (
    Cursor1 OUT CURS)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN Cursor1 FOR
        SELECT NO, TITLE, STARTDATE
        FROM TABLE_1;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a formal answer to this question, I will post here the answer of the owner. (I will delete this if the owner will include his answer here).

[UPDATE]

**It works now, I change all the data type of STARTDATE to DateTime and extract it from database without conversion.**